# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

When starting Tomcat in Eclipse I see this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1258)
...
```

However, earlier it logs this

```
INFO: Command line argument: -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.26/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.11.4/protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar: ....
```

And mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar does exist there. Also, mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar exists in the lib folder from which Eclipse is running it, /home/xyz/apache-tomcat-9.0.26/lib (and contents are identical). So it seems like it ought to be able to find java.sql.Driver. (hmm, unless it's the actual interface that it can't find rather than the implementation - but I don't know why that would suddenly be the case)

I have no idea what is causing that jar to be added as a -Xbootclasspath argument when eclipse runs tomcat. It doesn't appear in Run/Run Configurations/Arguments or Classpath. But unless Java is confused by finding it in two places, and just gives up instead of having one override the other, then I don't think it should matter anyway. (Also, I temporarily renamed the one in tomcat's lib and got the same error)

The context.xml for the database to be used:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/football" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        initialSize="10" maxTotal="100" minIdle="10" maxIdle="30"
        maxWaitMillis="10000" validationQuery="/* ping */ SELECT 1"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        username="zzzzzz" password="zzzzzzzz"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://yyyyyy/football?autoReconnect=true" />
```

"Hey, isn't this a duplicate question?" While the same error has been seen quite a number of times, I haven't found a solution which helps in this case (usually it's "you're missing the jar").

It was working with mysql-connector-java-5.1.32 but I've been forced to upgrade.

Pop!_OS 21.04, Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0), Tomcat 9.0.26, java-11-openjdk-amd64 (11.0.11)

The (almost) whole log console (whole was 3k too big):

```
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.26
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 16 2019 15:51:39 UTC
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.26.0
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            5.13.0-7614-generic
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Ubuntu
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/lordbah/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/lordbah/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.26
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:43191
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -javaagent:/home/lordbah/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1778/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/lordbah/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/lordbah/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.26
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/lordbah/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.26/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.11.4/protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-server/2.31/jersey-server-2.31.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.31/jersey-common-2.31.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.3/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.31/jersey-client-2.31.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.6/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-jaxb/2.31/jersey-media-jaxb-2.31.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/jakarta.inject/2.6.1/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/home/lordbah/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.26] using APR version [1.7.0].
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021]
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [419] milliseconds
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.26]
Oct 25, 2021 3:08:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1258)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.findBootstrapClassOrNull(System.java:2134)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$BootClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(ClassLoaders.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:640)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1077)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:561)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:341)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:557)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more

Oct 25, 2021 3:08:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/football-service]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/football-service]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1258)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.findBootstrapClassOrNull(System.java:2134)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$BootClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(ClassLoaders.java:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:640)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1077)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:561)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:341)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:557)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more

Oct 25, 2021 3:08:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.MultiThrowable: 2 wrapped Throwables: [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/football-service]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:920)
    ... 21 more

Oct 25, 2021 3:08:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.MultiThrowable: 2 wrapped Throwables: [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]][org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/football-service]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:920)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: A 'bootclasspath' is for __the core JVM classes__. By specifying it and not including a core runtime, you've removed most of java. You just want `-classpath`, not `-Xbootclasspath`.

Comment: Any idea what is creating that option when Eclipse launches Tomcat?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the highlighted line was doing it. I don't know how it got there but I deleted it and no longer see the -Xbootclasspath arguments or the java/sql/Driver NoClassDefFound.

[image: Screenshot of run configuration]